# Return true or false if an array is monotonic

Tags: javascript

I feel stupid for asking but why is this returning true when it should be false?

An array is monotonic if it is either monotone increasing or monotone decreasing.

An array A is monotone increasing if for all i <= j, A[i] <= A[j].  An array A is monotone decreasing if for all i <= j, A[i] >= A[j].

Return true if and only if the given array A is monotonic.

```
var isMonotonic = function(A) {
    let ascendOrder = A.sort((a,b) => a - b);
    console.log(ascendOrder);
    let descendOrder = A.sort((a,b) => b - a);
    console.log(descendOrder);
    if (A !== ascendOrder && A !== descendOrder) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
console.log(isMonotonic([1, 3, 2])); // false
```

Comment: If you want to take that approach, you'll need to (1) clone the `A` before sorting so as not to mutate it (2) iterate through each index of the array to compare against the same index in the other array

Comment: As a hint... `isAscending = a => a.slice(1).every((e,i) => e > a[i])`.

Comment: The same problem is with Java as well, equals and == is not the same.